# Failed to install miniconda on Opensuse 12.2

Tags: software-installation, opensuse, installer-anaconda

I am not all that familiar with Opensuse and I am now trying to install [miniconda](https://docs.conda.io/projects/conda/en/latest/user-guide/install/linux.html) on such an OS.

I have downloaded the [.sh installer](https://repo.anaconda.com/miniconda/Miniconda3-latest-Linux-x86_64.sh) and ran `bash Miniconda3-latest-Linux-x86_64.sh`

The installer did start and I agreed with the license.

Then I was asked about the installation location, which, according to the default values should be `/home/user/miniconda3`.

Upon confirmation of this location, I got the following error message shortly after

```
Miniconda3 will now be installed into this location:
/home/user/miniconda3

  - Press ENTER to confirm the location
  - Press CTRL-C to abort the installation
  - Or specify a different location below

[/home/user/miniconda3] >>> 
PREFIX=/home/user/miniconda3
Unpacking payload ...
tail: cannot open ‘+9231072’ for readingtail: cannot open ‘+2’ for reading: No such file or directory
: No such file or directory
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "tarfile.py", line 2297, in next
  File "tarfile.py", line 1093, in fromtarfile
  File "tarfile.py", line 1029, in frombuf
tarfile.EmptyHeaderError: empty header

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "conda.exe.py", line 62, in <module>
  File "tarfile.py", line 1601, in open
  File "tarfile.py", line 1482, in __init__
  File "tarfile.py", line 2312, in next
tarfile.ReadError: empty file
[10278] Failed to execute script conda.exe
ERROR: could not extract tar starting at offset 000000000000018891+9231072+2
```

I now see that a `/home/user/miniconda3` directory containing a `conda.exe` was created.

Does anyone know what is the background problem? As I said, I am very little familiar with Opensuse and the same installation method worked on my Ubuntu 18.04 LTS machine.

I also see that the version of the `tail` program that I have in the two machines are different. If I type `tail --version` on the OpenSuse machine I get:

```
tail (GNU coreutils) 8.16
Copyright (C) 2012 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
License GPLv3+: GNU GPL version 3 or later <http://gnu.org/licenses/gpl.html>.
This is free software: you are free to change and redistribute it.
There is NO WARRANTY, to the extent permitted by law.

Written by Paul Rubin, David MacKenzie, Ian Lance Taylor,
and Jim Meyering.
bhinckel@cr28603:~/downloads>
```

Which is quite old, whereas I get:

```
tail (GNU coreutils) 8.28
Copyright (C) 2017 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
License GPLv3+: GNU GPL version 3 or later <http://gnu.org/licenses/gpl.html>.
This is free software: you are free to change and redistribute it.
There is NO WARRANTY, to the extent permitted by law.

Written by Paul Rubin, David MacKenzie, Ian Lance Taylor,
and Jim Meyering.
```

On the Ubuntu machine.

Comment: Is there any reason you would use such an old release? It has been released almost three years ago and has reached end-of-life in January 2018. Did you choose the right architecture for your setup (32 Bit or 64 Bit)? I was able to install it without an issue on a (also older) SLES12-SP3 which has the code base of Leap 42.3.

Comment: An old release of the coreutils/ tail command,  you mean? I don't know, really. This is not my personal machine - it is a machine from work, so not managed by me. I did chose the right architecture (x86_64). What is the version of your `tail` command?

Comment: Alright, it could have been a test setup or something, just wanted to make you aware of it. I mean the OS openSUSE Leap 42.2 is at end-of-life since 2018. The tail version is 
    `host:~ # tail --version 
    tail (GNU coreutils) 8.25`